# Why is My Collection View Cell Color Selection Not Working

Tags: swift, colors, background, uicollectionview, cell

My cells were set to blue on StoryBoard but they remain blue (not red) even when I change cell backgroundColor when user selects cell. What's wrong with my code?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "throneCell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterViewCell
    let character = characters[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    onBoardingService.pickCharacter(character: character)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "throneCell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterViewCell
    let character = characters[indexPath.row]
    onBoardingService.removeCharacter(character: character)
}
```

[image: cell on Storyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "throneCell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterViewCell
```

With

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CharacterViewCell
```

> Don't use `dequeueReusableCell` out of `cellForItemAt`  as it'll return a cell that's not the clicked one

`didDeselectItemAt` may be called when the cell is not here so ,

```
guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CharacterViewCell else { return }
```

---

```
 var selectedIndex = 0

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "throneCell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterViewCell
    let character = characters[indexPath.row]

    if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
         onBoardingService.pickCharacter(character: character)
         cell.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red 
    else {
          cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
          onBoardingService.removeCharacter(character: character)
    }



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

---

Remove this method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "throneCell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterViewCell
    let character = characters[indexPath.row]
    onBoardingService.removeCharacter(character: character)
}
```

Regarding deselction of single item

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {  
    selectedIndex = selectedIndex == indexPath.row ? nil : indexPath.row 
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

and declare

```
var selectedIndex:Int?
```

Comment: It says this after running "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: great thanks! How would I let the user only pick 3 cells though and keep track of which are picked in terms of ranking (1st, 2nd, 3rd pick)?

Comment: instead of a `selectedIndex ` create an array , append to it inside `didSelectRowAt` and every time check arr count then  in `cellForRowAt` check `indexPath.row`  for coloring

Answer (score 0):

Try to add cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear on the didDeselectItemAt.

Like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "throneCell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterViewCell
  let character = characters[indexPath.row]
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
  onBoardingService.removeCharacter(character: character)
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work! What else do you think I should try?

Comment: try to add tableview.reloadData() on didSelectRow

Comment: I tried collectionView.reloadData and still doesn't work somebody HELP pls!! D: